# Is mixed content in a column a bad design?

Tags: database-design

I have a colleague who keeps putting mixed content in a column. For example this current case I'm struggling with is a column called "opts" which is an integer array. Depending on a type that is not even present in the current row, you have to join another table to find that out, this column may contain:

- a 0 or a 1 - meaning an on/off state
- a list of IDs from a table
- a list of IDs from a second table
- null in any other case

To me this looks more like clutter than organized data. So is there a database design concept that this violates or is it just my OCD? What should my arguments be when I try to persuade him not to do this anymore?

I'd like to add that the IDs in the table do not need foreign keys for reasons that are not worth getting into, the colleague does this with other stuff too, for ex another column in another table has either a string or a json text. What I'd do in these cases is to have more columns, one for each case, and complete only one of them and leave the rest as null.

Comment: To be honest, I  used to do that when the hard disk size was 40M. Yes that's correct. Space was a premium.  But I  stopped two decades ago. Queries and Reports are so much cleaner and easier with multiple columns. And database size will not increase significantly, 
if  nulls are stored in unused positions.

Comment: In addition to what SEarl wrote, you might want to look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+muck) - 1st post and also check out other posts in that link - als, check out the writings of Joe Celko on EAV - it's pretty much a disaster for an RDBMS. It has been used commercially ([Magento](https://blog.magestore.com/entity-attribute-value-in-magento/)) and [Aaron Betrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) (most points on dba.se) - so, try it if you must, but I would advise a conventional RDBMS data model if at all possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am first making some assumptions:

- "A list of IDs" means a comma separated string such as `1,2,3,4,5` etc
- Your column `opts` is a string datatype such as VARCHAR / NVARCHAR / CHAR etc

You don't mention your DBMS. My answer is based on SQL Server so some of the things I mention may not be relevant to other DBMS'

To me, the pattern you describe is "One True lookup table (OTLT)" this is where you have a single table of multiple entities that are differentiated by some key or value eg:

```
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
| ID |  category  | Name  |     DateCreated     |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | Person     | John  | 2022-12-29T00:00:00 |
|  2 | Person     | Jim   | 2022-12-29T01:00:00 |
|  3 | Department | I.T   | 2022-12-29T02:00:00 |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

This may be used because when a new entity type is created, it can be created by INSERTing data into a table rather than changing the database schema. It can potentially be valid when the different types of entities have common properties (in the case above - a name and a date created)

However, it starts to fall down when we want to add new properties to an entity, EG a person's age. In this case, we would add an age column to the table but value in that column would only have meaning for some of the rows in the table, this can quickly become messy and difficult to work with.

Some thoughts on why OTLT plus storing comma delimited lists is bad

For ease of explanation, I am going to say you have a row which has a list of PersonIDs that are stored in this table for some reason and that you have a separate person table where PersonID is unique

- Lack of constraint - if a particular entity type requires a 1 or a 0 but the column is VARCHAR, there is nothing to stop some other illegal value being entered such as 'abc' (perhaps a CHECK constraint but these are likely to become complicated,prone to error and need update everytime a new category is created)
- If we need to join to the person table to get any information about the one or more persons in the ID list, we are going to have to do a string split which can be awful for performance, it also relies on the comma delimted list being entered in a standard format
- We can't easily see all the people in the person table who are not listed in this table (again, we would achieve this through a left anti join)
- Indexing will be almost impossible
- It is more likely that the table will cause a blocking problem in your database as more queries will use it, most will be inefficient and slow for the reasons mentioned above meaning the locks will be longer and waiting queries will wait longer
- You mention the data doesn't need to be a foreign key but if it does in the future, you have a job on your hands to change the database schema
- Storage - assuming this column is VARCHAR, the storage requirements will be greater than if the correct data types were used (storing a 1 or 0 as a BIT data type costs 1 byte, VARCHAR would cost 3)
- Dependant on the length of the VARCHAR column, this could massively increase the amount of memory required to run queries - if SQL Server needs to sort this column, it assumes each row holds a VARCHAR value half the size of the varchar length and uses this estimate to grant the appropriate amount of memory. If your column is VARCHAR(MAX) and the query optimizer needs to sort this column, your server could quickly run out memory and new queries would have to wait until existing ones complete (Known as RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE waits)
- You are likely to introduce implicit conversions when comparing the column to something else which is usually bad for estimation and can cause numerous performance issues
- Permissions - what if I want a user to be able to update Departments but not people but they are both stored in the same table?

As for design concepts, comma delimted lists violate [first normal form](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php) and OTLT potentially violates [second normal form](https://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/second-normal-form-2nf.php)

FWIW, I have lived through the pain these patterns cause and they are just pure nasty IMO. Convincing those that create them to rip them out will probably require tests that evidence those bullets points above - when testing, don't neccesarily think how much data you have now, think 1, 3, 5 years time